# Updating Description of MXD Layers after metadata updated on source using ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, arcgis-10.2, metadata

Is there a way to force the update of the Description content in the Properties/General/Description of each feature layer in an MXD?

I frequently update metadata for each feature class in ArcCatalog, but these changes are not coming through to the feature layer in MXDs.

Using ArcGIS 10.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You can update properties of a layer in an mxd by accessing the layer in the mxd using the arcpy [layer](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) object.

Note that updating the metadata here is not updating the metadata of the dataset. I would recommend updating the dataset metadata as that will follow the dataset which is very important if you share the data with another person.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but this answer will hopefully help people still using 10. The script below will update mxd layers with the most current metadata. It uses [arcpy_metadata](https://github.com/ucd-cws/arcpy_metadata) which is opensource. I am not associated with the developer. The script below also uses a regular expression to find and replace xml tags, with a single space, in case the abstract has been formatted.

```
import arcpy_metadata as md
import re
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
lyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for lyr in lyrs:
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        mds = md.MetadataEditor(lyr.dataSource)
        desc = mds.abstract
        cl = re.compile('<.*?>') # prepare to get rid of xml tags
        clt = re.sub(cl, ' ', desc) # get rid of xml tags
        lyr.description = clt
        lyr.credits = mds.credits
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
mxd.save()
```